# Facebook api, sdk 4.0, php - uploading a photo from the server to user's facebook

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to build an app that allows the user to browse for a photo from their computer and post it onto facebook. Right now I have two php files: index.php and upload.php. Index checks whether there is a session etc, and requests for permissions and provides a login and a form for user to browse and submit a picture. The picture chosen will be then saved onto the server via in upload.php.

I am struggling with making an api request from another file that's not index.php. The facebook documentation for sdk 4.0 is so unclear. I know I have to include all the require_once and use facebook libraries again. However, do I have to create/check for a session again and ask for permissions? Or is there something I can do with the access token? If so, how do I call it? And is it possible to post a photo by fetching it from the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving the `access_token` in index.php, your second script just needs to make sure the access_token is set and valid (I'm assuming token is set in `$_SESSION` as `fb_token`). If the session does not exist or user_token is invalud, redirect the user back to index.php for the login flow.

You can do something like:

```
if ( isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
  // create FB session from Access Token
  $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );

  // the rest of your code here...

} else {
  // redirect back to index for login
  header( 'Location: index.php' );
}
```

[Have a look at the example here](https://www.webniraj.com/2014/05/01/facebook-api-php-sdk-updated-to-v4-0-0/).

Comment: I have " if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ ..........." in my upload.php which returns the file type to see if it's allowed and then saves in my upload folder on my server. Do I put that where you have stated "// the rest of your code here"? And then below it make my api requests? Thanks

Comment: Hmm, just used your code and it keeps directing me back to index.php.. so I assume there isn't a valid session or existing one? Not sure why though, I've looked at your example and used the same code in my index. Do you have any ideas where I may be going wrong?

Comment: Could I in the else bit, get the access token from my URL? (not sure how but in my URL code = access token right?)

Comment: Not sure where it is going wrong. I created and saved my session in index.php.. I also tried to use the get method to get the access token from the URL but that doesn't work either. It says the variable is undefined :S

Comment: Add debug code around your app to see what could be causing the issue. Use var_dump() and try...catch statements around the Facebook parts to catch any errors.

Comment: I think I know what to problem is. It's looking for the variable in my localhost url rather than the app url... Notice: Undefined index: code in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\upload.php on line 44. Do you know how to fix this? :S

Comment: You can do something like: `$code = isset( $_GET['code'] ) ? $_GET['code'] : '';`

Comment: I've already tried that but still get the error. Facebook api, creating a fb app is so hard, I keep getting stuck on such small milestones :(

Comment: This is really strange. I just copied my upload.php into my index.php. I used echo $code and when I click log in and does echo my access token. Should I just do it all in one script? :S